# An approximation or equation to find the angle of inclination of an inclined path

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was making a [free-body diagram of a vehicle moving along an inclined path](http://clay6.com/mpaimg/ph%2021.jpg), but I have a question about how I can obtain an equation for the angle of inclination as a function of displacement, or how I can approximate that value of the angle when the vehicle moves?

Comment: are you saying the tilt of the ramp is changing over time?

Comment: @zhutchens1 Assuming the vehicle moves on an arbitrary road, then the angle of inclination will change over time.

Comment: While its not based in distance directly, you could use the arctangent of its instantaneous velocities taken from the derivatives of its position vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the left endpoint of the road as the origin, then you the relationship between Cartesian and polar coordinates can be useful. For a car located at $\mathbf{r}$, we can say that

$$ x = ||\mathbf{r}||\cos\theta. $$

Then $$\theta = \arccos \left(\frac{x}{||\mathbf{r}||}\right), $$

where both $x(t)$ and $r(t)$ are functions of time, with $r(t)$ having the dependence $r^2(t) = x^2(t) + y^2(t)$ for every individual point along the curve.

Therefore, this can give you a function $\theta(x,y) = \theta(\mathbf{r})$ to use as the car slides down the slope with velocity $\mathbf{\dot r}(t)$.